# Webpack parser problem with legacy project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, dependencies

I started working on a 5-years old python+react project. I had many problems regarding old packages or incompatibility. I managed  to fix most of the problems that I faced except for this one:

```
ERROR in ./app/index.js
Module parse failed: /home/kaiz3n/Desktop/iris/iris-agent/app/index.js Unexpected token (37:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (37:6)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (/home/kaiz3n/Desktop/iris/iris-agent/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/home/kaiz3n/Desktop/iris/iris-agent/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/home/kaiz3n/Desktop/iris/iris-agent/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1822:12)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (/home/kaiz3n/Desktop/iris/iris-agent/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1715:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (/home/kaiz3n/Desktop/iris/iris-agent/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1692:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (/home/kaiz3n/Desktop/iris/iris-agent/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1637:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (/home/kaiz3n/Desktop/iris/iris-agent/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1620:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (/home/kaiz3n/Desktop/iris/iris-agent/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1597:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprList (/home/kaiz3n/Desktop/iris/iris-agent/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2165:22)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseSubscripts (/home/kaiz3n/Desktop/iris/iris-agent/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1741:35)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (/home/kaiz3n/Desktop/iris/iris-agent/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1718:17)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (/home/kaiz3n/Desktop/iris/iris-agent/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1692:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (/home/kaiz3n/Desktop/iris/iris-agent/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1637:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (/home/kaiz3n/Desktop/iris/iris-agent/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1620:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (/home/kaiz3n/Desktop/iris/iris-agent/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1597:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExpression (/home/kaiz3n/Desktop/iris/iris-agent/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1573:21)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/home/kaiz3n/Desktop/iris/iris-agent/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:727:47)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (/home/kaiz3n/Desktop/iris/iris-agent/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:638:25)
    at Parser.parse (/home/kaiz3n/Desktop/iris/iris-agent/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:516:17)
    at Object.parse (/home/kaiz3n/Desktop/iris/iris-agent/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:3098:39)
    at Parser.parse (/home/kaiz3n/Desktop/iris/iris-agent/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
    at NormalModule.<anonymous> (/home/kaiz3n/Desktop/iris/iris-agent/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
    at NormalModule.onModuleBuild (/home/kaiz3n/Desktop/iris/iris-agent/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
    at nextLoader (/home/kaiz3n/Desktop/iris/iris-agent/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
    at /home/kaiz3n/Desktop/iris/iris-agent/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:259:5
    at Storage.finished (/home/kaiz3n/Desktop/iris/iris-agent/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:38:16)
    at /home/kaiz3n/Desktop/iris/iris-agent/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:123:16
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (node:internal/fs/read_file_context:75:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "iris-electron",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "babel": "babel",
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.2",
    "react": "^15.0.2",
    "react-ace": "^5.0.1",
    "react-data-grid": "^2.0.33",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.2",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-router": "^2.4.0",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.4",
    "react-split-pane": "^0.1.63",
    "react-syntax-highlighter": "^5.1.3",
    "react-vega-lite": "^1.0.1",
    "redux": "^3.5.2",
    "vega": "^3.0.0-rc6",
    "vega-lite": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.6",
    "babel-core": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^6.0.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "electron": "^1.6.5",
    "electron-packager": "^8.6.0",
    "eslint": "^2.9.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^5.0.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.16.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.0.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^0.9.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.0.2",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.2.0",
    "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.1.1",
    "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.0.11",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "sass-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "stats-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        'react-hot-loader/patch',
        path.join(__dirname, 'app/index.js')
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: ''
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          template: 'app/index.tpl.html',
          inject: 'body',
          filename: 'index.html'
        }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
        })
    ],
    //eslint: {
      //  configFile: '.eslintrc',
       // failOnWarning: false,
        //failOnError: false
    //},
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel'
            },
            {
                test: /\.json?$/,
                loader: 'json'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: 'style!css!sass?modules&localIdentName=[name]---[local]---[hash:base64:5]'
            },
            { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?[a-z0-9#=&.]+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff' },
            { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?[a-z0-9#=&.]+)?$/, loader: 'file' }
        ]
    }
};
```